# Hint for JTextField / JPasswordField

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextfield, hint

I built a class extending the JTextField class and an own hint function.

```
package functions;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TextField extends JTextField {

private String hint;
private Color cForeground;
private Color cHint;

public void setHint(String s) {
    hint = s;
    cForeground = getForeground();

    setText(hint);
    cHint = new Color(cForeground.getRed(), cForeground.getGreen(),
            cForeground.getBlue(), cForeground.getAlpha() / 2);

    addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            if (getText().equals("")) {
                setForeground(cHint);
                setText(hint);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            if (getText().equals(hint)) {
                setText("");
                setForeground(cForeground);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

1) At the moment my hint only shows up when it's not focused. But I want my hint to be visible when it's empty - also when it's focused. I played around with `ActionListener` instead of `FocusListener`, but I didn't get it.

2) I want the same thing for JPasswordField, but I don't want to write the same method in 2 different classes. Is there a way I can point at the same method from both classes while one extends JTextField and the other one JPasswordField?

3) I decide whether the hint shall be shown by calling `getText()`, but that's not nice in handling with passwords (I don't want to get blamed for logging them...). Is there another way wich would prevent this?

Btw: I know about `TextPrompt`, but I want to build an own simple solution.

Comment: `I know about TextPrompt, but I want to build an own simple solution` - then start with something that works and customize it for your requirements. Maybe it is not easy to create a simple solution. `But I want my hint to be visible when it's empty - also when it's focused.`  TextPrompt does this. `I want the same thing for JPasswordField, but I don't want to write the same method in 2 different classes` well once again Text Prompt shows you how to do this, so learn from a working example.

Comment: My comments are made assuming you are talking about this [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) class.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want a thing called placeholder in HTML. Then override `paintComponent` method like this:

```
public class STextField extends JTextField{
    public static final Color placeholderColor = new Color(cForeground.getRed(), cForeground.getGreen(), cForeground.getBlue(), cForeground.getAlpha() / 2);
    public STextField(String placeholder){
        this.placeholder = placeholder;
    }
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics pG) {
        super.paintComponent(pG);
        if(placeholder.length() == 0 || getText().length() > 0)
            return;
        final Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) pG;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(placeholderColor);
        int offset = 4; // This value depends on height of text field. Probably can be calculated from font size.
        g.drawString(placeholder, getInsets().left, pG.getFontMetrics().getMaxAscent() + offset);
    }
    private String placeholder;
}
```